# Change the border radius of underline tab indicator

Tags: flutter

How do you change the border radius of an underline tab indicator? If I use Box Decoration then the indicator covers the whole tab instead[image]

Comment: This Answer on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60207984/14072873

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom indicator similar to this article, https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-custom-tab-indicator-for-tabbar-d72bbc6c9d0c, but replace `drawCircle(...)` with `drawRRect(...)`.

Comment: I am so close from pulling it off! Only one thing left and that is I want the indicator to take the size of the label of the tab. Any chance I could somehow convert TabIndicatorSize.label to a double?

Comment: In `void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration cfg)`, `cfg.size.width` is equal to the width of the indicatorSize.

Answer (score 1):

> It's too late to answer but you can try this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TabBarIndicator extends Decoration {
final BoxPainter _painter;

TabBarIndicator({required Color color, required double radius})
  : _painter = _TabBarIndicator(color, radius);

@override
BoxPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback? onChanged]) => _painter;
}

class _TabBarIndicator extends BoxPainter {
final Paint _paint;
final double radius;

_TabBarIndicator(Color color, this.radius)
  : _paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..isAntiAlias = true;

@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration){
final Offset customOffset = offset +
    Offset(configuration.size!.width / 2,
        configuration.size!.height - radius - 5);

canvas.drawRRect(
    RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
      Rect.fromCenter(
          center: customOffset,
          width: configuration.size!.width,
          height: 4),
      topLeft: Radius.circular(radius),
      topRight: Radius.circular(radius),
    ),
    _paint);
  }
 }
```

> And use it like this.

```
TabBar(
indicator: TabBarIndicator(color: Colors.green, radius: 4),),
```

Comment: I have been looking for a solution that is exactly this with the BoxPainter FOREVER! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I just apply the precedent solution: the final code can be:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class CustomIndicator extends Decoration {
  final BoxPainter _painter;
  CustomIndicator({required Color color, required double radius})
      : _painter = _CustomIndicator(color, radius);
  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback? onChanged]) => _painter;
  //   throw UnimplementedError();
  // }
}
class _CustomIndicator extends BoxPainter {
  final Paint _paint;
  final double radius;
  _CustomIndicator(Color color, this.radius)
      : _paint = Paint()
          ..color = color
          ..isAntiAlias = true;
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration) 
{
    final Offset customOffset = offset +
        Offset(configuration.size!.width / 2,
            configuration.size!.height - radius - 5);
    //canvas.drawCircle(customOffset, radius, _paint);
    canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
            Rect.fromCenter(
                center: customOffset,
                vwidth: configuration.size!.width,
                height: 3),
            Radius.circular(radius)),
        _paint);
  }
}
```